# Can somebody help me setting up a printer?

Tags: lubuntu, printing

Hello Ubuntu community

I'm using Lubuntu 20.04 LTS and need to do some printing. I have a Brother MFC-8860DN, but I can't find it in the printer drivers list, so I asked Brother for help. They said I needed to use the drivers for the HL-1250, but now, it doesn't work anymore. So I contacted Brother again, and now they said that I need to contact a Linux expert and use the drivers on https://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadlist.aspx?c=be&lang=nl&prod=mfc8860dn_all&os=127&flang=English, while they don't have a clear manual. Can someone help me please?

Thanks
Irsu85

Comment: Download .deb files from https://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadlist.aspx?c=in&lang=en&prod=mfc8860dn_all&os=128 and for installation  details visit https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=590793